# Python Decorator is spitting out None

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-decorators

I am learning some new topics in python, and I finally got to decorators, which seems cool and all except theres one major issue. Below is the code I have running:

```
def new_dec(ori_func):
    def WrapFunc():
        print("First Line")
        ori_func()
        print("Second line")
    return WrapFunc

def new_func():
    print("This is the new function")

ThisFunc = new_dec(new_func)
print(ThisFunc())
```

However, when this code is executed it outputs:

```
First Line
This is the new function
Second line
None
```

And I do not remember adding a None statement, is this possibly a type variable that has been added? Why is this happening, and how can this be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a function returns None. You just have to call the function to get what you expect.

```
def new_dec(ori_func):
    def WrapFunc():
        print("First Line")
        ori_func()
        print("Second line")
    return WrapFunc

def new_func():
    print("This is the new function")

ThisFunc = new_dec(new_func)
ThisFunc() # get rid of the print statement
```

Answer (score 2):

You have four print statements. So four things get printed. And by default a function returns `None`:

```
>>> def f(): pass
>>> print(f())
None
```

Check what happens if you define:

```
def new_dec(ori_func):
    def WrapFunc():
        print("First Line")
        ori_func()
        print("Second line")
        return "Fourth Line"
    return WrapFunc
```

Alternatively you can remove the fourth print:

```
# print(ThisFunc())
ThisFunc()
```